# "zur Aussage bringen", ist dieser Ausdruck richtig?

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich habe eine Tabelle/ein Bild vorliegen. Darin steht:

> Die Jugendlichen in Deutschland werden nach deren (eigener) Meinung
>   gefragt, was sie über Globalisierung denken.

Nun soll ich eine Einleitung dazu schreiben. Das habe ich gemacht:

> Das vorliegende Schaubild mit dem Titel "Globalisierung bedeutet"
>   informiert darüber, wie viel Prozent der Jugendlichen in Deutschland
>   zur Aussage bringen, was die Globalisierung verursacht.

Kann ich in diesem Satz "zur Aussage bringen" verwenden? Oder ist dieser Ausdruck falsch?

[image]

Comment: @Robert, der ganze Satz ergibt keinen Sinn. Mein Vorschlag wäre: "Das vorliegende Schaubild mit dem Titel " Globalisierung bedeutet " zeigt, wie Jugendliche in Deutschland über die Globalisierung denken."

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, wie ich die Frage anders redigieren soll/kann. Ich bin so hilflos :(

Comment: @Robert: jetzt ist die Frage aber doch gut. :)

Comment: Der Satz würde Sinn ergeben, wenn das Schaubild zeigen würde, dass 70% dazu etwas zur Aussage bringen und 30% nicht. Ich schätze aber, dass unterschiedliche Aussagen gruppiert und prozentual dargestellt werden, dann passt es nicht.

Comment: Was meinst du konkret mit "was Globalisierung versursacht"? Meinst du "welche Folgen Globalisierung hat" oder "welche Ursachen Globalisierung hat"? Dein Satz kann in beide Richtungen verstanden werden...

Comment: @Robert It seems you've tried to add the picture, but accidentally inserted it to one of the answers and not your own question. Thus, I've rejected your edit (on that answer) and inserted the image here. I hope that is ok with you. In addition, please check the rotation of an image before posting it for convenience of your readers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Satz

> Das vorliegende Schaubild mit dem Titel "Globalisierung bedeutet" informiert darüber, wie viel Prozent der Jugendlichen in Deutschland zur Aussage bringen, was die Globalisierung verursacht.

ist rein grammatisch gesehen durchaus richtig. Aber stilistisch ist er unschön.

**1) Kanzleistil**

Generell sind Nominalwendungen wie

- zur Anwendungen bringen --> anwenden
- in Verkehr bringen --> verbreiten
- zur Durchführung bringen --> durchführen
- in Erwägung ziehen --> erwägen
- zum Verkauf bringen --> verkaufen
- zur Aussage bringen --> aussagen, sagen, angeben, erklären

typische Erscheinungen des deutschen Kanzleistils (Bürokratensprache, Beamtensprache). Man sollte sie in so gut wie allen Textgattungen vermeiden. Sie können praktisch immer durch reine Verben ersetzt werden (wie oben ja schon zu sehen ist).

**2) Ausdruck passt nicht ins thematische Umfeld**

Darüberhinaus ist "zur Aussage bringen" hier auch noch in einem unpassenden Kontext verwendet. "Zur Aussage bringen" würde allenfalls noch in einem Polizeiprotokoll auftauchen, nämlich wenn jemand eine förmliche, protokollierte Aussage bei der Polizei gemacht hat. Aber auch in einem Polizeibericht ist der Ausdruck "zur Aussage bringen" nicht gut und könnte ohne Weiteres durch kürzere, weniger umständliche Formulierungen ersetzt werden.

**Bessere Lösungen**

Eine typische, akzeptable Formulierung in einem Zeitungsartikel oder sonstigen sachlichen Bericht wäre etwa

> Das vorliegende Schaubild mit dem Titel "Globalisierung bedeutet..." informiert darüber, was Jugendliche in Deutschland als Auswirkungen der Globalisierung ansehen.

Oder etwas eleganter (indem überflüssige Teile weggelassen werden):

> Das Schaubild "Globalisierung bedeutet..." zeigt, was Jugendliche in Deutschland als Auswirkungen der Globalisierung ansehen.

Jedoch: Wir können nicht wirklich sagen, was die Jugendlichen meinen oder glauben. Wir können nur berichten, was sie uns mitgeteilt haben. Darum ist es gute Praxis, solche statistischen Auskünfte auch entsprechend vorsichtig zu formulieren. Eine logisch saubere Formulierung, die auch in einem wissenschaftlichen Text haltbar ist, wäre daher:

> Das Schaubild mit dem Titel "Globalisierung bedeutet..." zeigt, was Jugendliche in Deutschland als Auswirkungen von Globalisierung **angeben**.

Andere Varianten:

> Das Schaubild mit dem Titel "Globalisierung bedeutet..." zeigt, welche Auswirkungen auf ihr eigenes Leben Jugendliche in Deutschland der Globalisierung **zuschreiben**.
>
> Das Schaubild zeigt, was Globalsierung nach Aussage von Jugendlichen in Deutschland für wahrnehmbare Folgen hat.

---

Merke wohl: Wenn das alles Dir hochkompliziert erscheint: Es *ist* kompliziert. Du hast es hier mit einem ziemlich verwickelten Sachverhalt zu tun. Dein Anfangssatz war dafür gar nicht so schlecht.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass es in dem Schaubild und der Umfrage um *die Ursachen der Globalisierung*, sondern um die *Folgen der Globalisierung* geht ("..., was Globalisierung verursacht..." kann beides heißen!). Das wäre erstmal zu klären.

Comment: Die Einschränkung auf Polizeiprotokolle teile ich nicht, auch wenn ich die Einordnung als bürokratischen Stil bejahe. Als nüchterner Kommentar bei einem Diagramm muss das aber keine schlechte Wahl sein, wie ich hier zum Ausdruck bringne möchte. Punkt 1 ist schon hahnebüchen! Du willst nachzählen, ob etwas mehr Folgen als Ursachen hat? Selbst wenn das ginge - inwiefern leitet sich daraus die Pflicht ab, nur den Gewinner des Vergleichs betrachten zu dürfen? Jede Lücke ist besser als dieser Punkt 1. Punkt 3 ist, wennman pedantisch ist, richtig, aber unüblich bei der Darstlg. von Meinungsumfragen.

Comment: @userunknown  Zur Frage von Ursachen der Globalisierung: Nein, ich will natürlich nicht nachzählen, ob "Globalisierung" mehr Ursachen oder mehr Folgen hat. Ich sehe aber das Problem, dass es schwierig ist, *Ursachen* für Globalisierung zu benennen. Das Wort nur so hinzuwerfen, bringt nichts. Es kommt vollkommen darauf an, was du unter "Globalisierung" überhaupt verstehst. Natürlich kann man für jegliches Phänomen letztlich Voraussetzungen oder Entstehungsbedingungen benennen. Ich zweifle aber, dass der OP eine so komplexe Frage im Sinne hatte.

Comment: @tofro   Ja, stimmt, man kann "was die Globalisierung versursacht" auch verstehen im Sinne von "welche Folgen Globalisierung hat". Aber das wäre doch eher eine etwas "gewollte" interpretation des Formulierung im gegebenen Kontext. (Angesichts der generellen Unbeholfenheit im Ausdruck des Originalsatzes ist natürlich alles möglich...)

Comment: Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass man Jugendliche in einer Umfrage nach den *Ursachen* der Globalisierung fragt, halte ich für einigermaßen gering. Die Frage nach den von ihnen befürchteten *Folgen* halte ich für sehr viel wahrscheinlicher. Und eine **gewollte** Interpretation ist das überhaupt nicht. Es ist eine vollkommen legitime, vor allem, wenn der Satz von jemandem stammt, der offensichtlich im Deutschen noch nicht ganz sattelfest ist. Ich denke eher, es ist illegitim, über den Kopf des Verfassers hinwegzuinterpretieren, was er wohl gemeint hat.

Comment: @tofro  Die Geschichte hat dir rechtgegeben. Ich habe den Beitrag entsprechend angepasst.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: bitte nimm davon Abstand ganze Absätze mit wortreichen Erklärungen zu füllen in denen Du lediglich sagst, dass du etwas gelöscht hast. So etwas ist für diese Frage und Anwort sowohl jetzt als auch für später völlig unwichtig.

Comment: Jetzt, da man das Diagramm lesen kann, ist wohl geklärt, dass gefragt wird, wofür die Globalisierung Ursache ist. Und dass man mit diesen Jugendlichen (? - und jungen Erwachsenen) mal ein paar Wörtchen reden sollte. Ich hätte übrigens keine Schwierigkeit damit Ursachen der Globalisierung zu benennen. Deinen eigenen Maßstäben folgend solltest Du aber die eigentlich gute Antwort "Das Schaubild … zeigt, was Jugendliche … als Auswirkungen von Globalisierung angeben." zu "zeigt angeblich, was Jugendliche" abändern, denn da hast Du ja auch nur das Wort der Studienersteller. :)

Answer (score 2):

*"Wie viele Prozent etwas zur Aussage bringen"* ist in der Tat nicht einfach zu verstehen.

Mein Vorschlag einer Einleitung wäre:

> Das vorliegende Schaubild mit dem Titel "Globalisierung bedeutet" veranschaulicht, wie verschiedene Meinungen zur Globalisierung unter Jugendlichen in Deutschland verteilt sind.

Comment: Ich habe heute durch Ihre Antworten/Vorschläge sehr viel dazugelernt. Ich bin Ihnen allen sehr dankbar!

Comment: @Robert: Die erwünschte Form hier seine Dankbarkeit auszudrücken besteht darin, den Pfeil nach oben, links von der Antwort, anzuklicken und die beste Antwort mit dem Häkchen auszuzeichnen.

Comment: "... wie verschiedene Meinungen... verteilt sind" ist zwar eine elegante Lösung für den statistischen Teil des Schaubilds. Aber inhaltlich gehst du damit schon sehr weit in die Breite, weg von dem doch eigentlich klar formulierten "was Globalisierung versursacht".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: wir wissen ja gar nicht, ob überhaupt nach den "Ursachen" gefragt wurde, dann ist eine allgemeine Formulierung besser.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann und Takkat Nur zur Info: Die Abbildung wurde inzwischen ergänzt.